# Error when ex mkvirtualenv in Mountain Lion

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, osx-mountain-lion

I have Mountain Lion and I installed virtualenv using this method:

```
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
echo "export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/Envs" >> $BASH_CONFIG_FILE
echo "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> $BASH_CONFIG_FILE
source ~/.bashrc
```

There is a problem when I try to create the virtualenv with this command:

```
mkvirtualenv test
```

I receive this error:

```
New python executable in test/bin/python
Installing setuptools...........
Complete output from command /Users/marco/Envs/test/bin/python -c "#!python
\"\"\"Bootstra...sys.argv[1:])

" /Library/Python/2.7/...ols-0.6c11-py2.7.egg:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 279, in <module>
File "<string>", line 207, in main
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/extension.py", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/marco/Envs/test/lib/python2.7/distutils/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
exec(open(os.path.join(distutils_path, '__init__.py')).read())
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/__init__.py'
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 8, in <module>
load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.7.2', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 942, in main
never_download=options.never_download)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1052, in create_environment
search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 598, in install_setuptools
search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 570, in _install_req
cwd=cwd)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1020, in call_subprocess
% (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/marco/Envs/test/bin/python -c "#!python
\"\"\"Bootstra...sys.argv[1:])
" /Library/Python/2.7/...ols-0.6c11-py2.7.egg failed with error code 1
```

Can you help me?

Thanks!
Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have setuptools installed,

Install it from [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#cygwin-mac-os-x-linux-other)

if you upgraded from lion to mountain lion, the python install is broken due to some changes in the file-system, ideally you should install command line tools from xcode, then python from python website, then setuptools from python website and then pip via easy_install, everything will work afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:

Xcode 4 doesn't automatically install the command line tools.

Basically, install Xcode, go into Preferences and then Downloads and install "Command Line Tools". It works now.

:)