# Can't use mkvirtualenv, "site-packages/_markerlib" permission denied

Tags: python, virtualenv

Edit, this seems to be a general permissions issue:

```
The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or the distutils default setting) was:
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?
```

---

I found this questions, which is exactly my problem, but I don't have a `~/.pydistutils.cfg` file:

[virtualenv: could not create '/lib/python2.7': Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979749/virtualenv-could-not-create-lib-python2-7-permission-denied/18979750)

I also definitely have setuptools and command line tools installed as mentioned here: [Error when ex mkvirtualenv in Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026843/error-when-ex-mkvirtualenv-in-mountain-lion)

I installed everything with sudo, but I can't use sudo here:

```
sudo: mkvirtualenv: command not found
```

Traceback:

```
mkvirtualenv myenv
......stuff here......

build/lib/setuptools/_backport/hashlib
running install_lib
creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_markerlib
error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_markerlib': Permission denied
----------------------------------------
...Installing Setuptools...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.10.1', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 821, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 961, in create_environment
    install_sdist('Setuptools', 'setuptools-*.tar.gz', py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 932, in install_sdist
    filter_stdout=filter_install_output)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 899, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/cbron/.virtualenvs/sam/bin/python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --record record failed with error code 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo chown -R your-username:wheel /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

You may need to chmod the permissions of the dir and/or uninstall and re-install virtualenv:

```
sudo pip uninstall virtualenv
sudo pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper
sudo pip install virtualenv 
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
echo "source `which virtualenvwrapper.sh`" >> ~/.bash_profile 
. ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Check your path, it might not be at /Library/Python/2.7/

Comment: Well, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232421/virtualenvwrapper-commands-arent-working/13736980#comment40326915_13736980) i found the solution..!